# assets:precompile tries to compile a sass partial when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

Any idea why Rails' assets:precompile would try to compile a sass partial _accounts.css.sass when it's not listed in my precompile list?

application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true

config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', 'controllers/*.js', 'controllers/admin/*.js', 'controllers/shared/*.js', '*.coffee', 'application.css.sass', '*.css', '*.png', '*.jpg', '*.scss.erb']
```

_accounts.css.sass is only included by application.css.sass which has:

```
@import "account"
```

The error is:

```
Undefined mixin 'column'. (in _account.css.sass)
```

...because it uses compass, but the application.css.sass imports compass before importing _accounts.css.sass, so the partial shouldn't need to import compass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file names/patterns in the list of things to precompile do not refer to the filenames of things to precompile. Instead they refer to the results of precompilation i.e. asking for '*.css' to be precompiled means precompile anything that if compiled would result in a .css file. In particular, a .css.sass file like your _account file will be precompiled.

Comment: Ok, but won't I want my application.css.sass to be compiled, but not the others? What then is the appropriate setting there? Thanks!

Comment: Then just ask for application.css to be compiled (which is on the list by default) and any other "top level" CSS files ( for example you might have an admin.css and mobile.css)